# provider.backends( ) not responding in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

[image]

please in need some help  I want to get a list of the providers in Qiskit and i use the command providers.backends() yet it says provider not defined. any suggestions.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well try doing this as it worked for me

```
IBMQ.save_account("your_API_id", overwrite=True)
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
provider.backends()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your IBMQ account first.

```
IBMQ.save_account("your IBMQ credentials")
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
provider.backends()
```

For more details on loading your IBMQ account checkout this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4EkW4VwhcI&list=PLOFEBzvs-Vvp2xg9-POLJhQwtVktlYGbY&index=2).